# QT-FTP Upload Error

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qnetworkreply

I'm trying to upload a simple txt file to ftp server but getting "QNetworkReply::ContentOperationNotPermittedError" reply from the server and i think it is about my file hierarchy.

Here is the file order of my ftp server and my qt-ftp configuration :

[image: File Order]
[image: FTP Information]

```
    QUrl url("f13-preview.125mb.com/www/home/repo/test.txt");
    url.setHost("f13-preview.125mb.com");
    url.setUserName("1896230");
    url.setPassword("mypassword");
    url.setPath("f13-preview.125mb.com/www/home/repo/");
    url.setScheme("ftp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get, why do you use QNetwork instead awesome [QFtp module](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtftp/source/75b21b033f413b4a32cc7e0cd6b780f59beadf18:), that provides all necessary for work with ftp?

```
QFtp *ftp = new QFtp(parent);
ftp->connectToHost("f13-preview.125mb.com");
ftp->login("1896230", "mypassword");
```

and then use [QFtp::put](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qftp.html#put-2). That's all you need.

Comment: i'm using QT5, and QFtp has deprecated after QT4. And it seems i should use QNetworkAccessManager instead of QFtp.

Comment: It's not deprecated (because module becomes deprecated after alternative comes, for QFtp there is no alternative, only raw QNetwork) just moved to additional module. It's works with Qt5 very well, I used many times.

Comment: well, i didn't know that, thanks so much! QFtp is way much easier than NetworkAccessMenager.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the QUrl as below and solved the problem, don'T know why but now i'm struglinng with segmentation fault.

```
QUrl url("fftp://f13-preview.125mb.com/repo/test.txt");
    if(url.isValid())
    {
        url.setHost("f13-preview.125mb.com");
        url.setUserName("1896230");
        url.setPassword("mypassword");
        url.setScheme("ftp");
        url.setPort(21);
    }
```